# How do I get Google to index changes made to my website's keywords?

Tags: seo, keyword, title

I have made changes to my website's keywords, description, and title, but Google is not indexing the new keyword. Instead, I have found that Google is indexing the older one.

How can I get Google to index my site using the new keywords that I have added?

Comment: How long have you waited? It usually takes some time to re-index.

Comment: I am guessing he just did it.

Comment: how much time it will take to re-index.pls?

Comment: how to edit google meta verfication code in joomla 1.5 websites index page

Answer (score 0):

Periods between crawling a page vary a *lot* across pages. A post to SO will be crawled and indexed by Google in seconds. Your personal page that hasn't changed content in 20 years might not even be crawled as much as once a year.

Submitting a sitemap to the [webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) will likely re-crawl your website to validate your sitemap. You could use this to speed up the re-crawling.

However, as @Charles noted, the `keywords` meta-tag is mostly ignored by Google. So it sounds like you're wasting your time.

Comment: how to edit google meta verfication code in joomla 1.5 websites index page.